# IJK MediaCodec Buffer (J4A) not loading

Tags: android-mediacodec, ijkplayer

**while using ijkmediaplayer,** necessary packages from the J4A loader is not loading (like MediacodecInfo, MediaCodecBufferInfo, java.nio.ByteBuffer, Buffer) That's why I am getting an error of insufficient resources to instantiate the decoder.

*02-21 14:23:59.335 2719-16555/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to call stream on OUTPUT due to HW_OVERLOAD
02-21 14:23:59.335 2719-16555/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: empty_this_buffer_proxy failure due to HW overload
02-21 14:23:59.337 2719-16555/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: ERROR: Sending OMX_ErrorInsufficientResources to Client
02-21 14:23:59.341 2719-16555/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to qbuf to driver
02-21 14:23:59.343 2719-16555/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to qbuf to driver*

Can anyone please tell me why J4A buffer modules are not getting loaded or called?
How to resolve this issue?